# Control radio button with button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I built this color picker for each product feature using radio buttons and CSS. The problem I could not work out how to remotely select radio button using JS.

Here is the structure for Color picker variable product style.

```css
h1 { display:block; text-align: center;}
            *, *:before, *:after {
              box-sizing: border-box;
            }
            
           #colorPicker {
             width:400px;
             margin:0 auto;
             height:520px;
             border:1px solid #eaeaea;
           }
         
            .slider {
              height: 100%;
              width:100%;
              position: relative;
              overflow: hidden;
              display: -webkit-box;
              display: -webkit-flex;
              display: -ms-flexbox;
              display: flex;
              -webkit-flex-flow: row nowrap;
                  -ms-flex-flow: row nowrap;
                      flex-flow: row nowrap;
              -webkit-box-align: end;
              -webkit-align-items: flex-end;
                  -ms-flex-align: end;
                      align-items: flex-end;
              -webkit-box-pack: center;
              -webkit-justify-content: center;
                  -ms-flex-pack: center;
                      justify-content: center;
            }
            .slider__nav {
              width: 30px;
              height: 30px;
              margin: 2rem 5px;
              z-index: 10;
              border:1px solid #BBB;
              cursor: pointer;
              -webkit-appearance: none;
                 -moz-appearance: none;
                      appearance: none;
              -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
                      backface-visibility: hidden;
            }
            .slider__nav:checked {
              -webkit-animation: check 0.4s linear forwards;
                      animation: check 0.4s linear forwards;
            }
            .slider__nav:checked:nth-of-type(1) ~ .slider__inner {
              left: 0%;
            }
            .slider__nav:checked:nth-of-type(2) ~ .slider__inner {
              left: -100%;
            }
            .slider__nav:checked:nth-of-type(3) ~ .slider__inner {
              left: -200%;
            }
            .slider__nav:checked:nth-of-type(4) ~ .slider__inner {
              left: -300%;
            }
            .slider__nav:checked:nth-of-type(5) ~ .slider__inner {
              left: -400%;
            }
            .slider__nav:checked:nth-of-type(6) ~ .slider__inner {
              left: -500%;
            }
            .slider__nav:checked:nth-of-type(7) ~ .slider__inner {
              left: -600%;
            }
            .slider__nav:checked:nth-of-type(8) ~ .slider__inner {
              left: -700%;
            }
            .slider__nav:checked:nth-of-type(9) ~ .slider__inner {
              left: -800%;
            }
            .slider__nav:checked:nth-of-type(10) ~ .slider__inner {
              left: -900%;
            }
            .slider__nav:checked:nth-of-type(11) ~ .slider__inner {
              left: -1000%;
            }
            .slider__inner {
              position: absolute;
              top: 0;
              left: 0;
              width: 1100%;
              height: 100%;
              -webkit-transition: left 0.4s;
              transition: left 0.4s;
              display: -webkit-box;
              display: -webkit-flex;
              display: -ms-flexbox;
              display: flex;
              -webkit-flex-flow: row nowrap;
                  -ms-flex-flow: row nowrap;
                      flex-flow: row nowrap;
            }
            .slider__contents {
              height: 100%;
              padding: 2rem;
              text-align: center;
              display: -webkit-box;
              display: -webkit-flex;
              display: -ms-flexbox;
              display: flex;
              
              -webkit-box-flex: 1;
              -webkit-flex: 1;
                  -ms-flex: 1;
                      flex: 1;
              -webkit-flex-flow: column nowrap;
                  -ms-flex-flow: column nowrap;
                      flex-flow: column nowrap;
              -webkit-box-align: center;
              -webkit-align-items: center;
                  -ms-flex-align: center;
                      align-items: center;
              -webkit-box-pack: center;
              -webkit-justify-content: center;
                  -ms-flex-pack: center;
                      justify-content: center;
            }
        
            
            @-webkit-keyframes check {
              50% {
                outline-color: #333;
                box-shadow: 0 0 0 12px #333, 0 0 0 36px rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.2);
              }
              100% {
                outline-color: #333;
                box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 #333, 0 0 0 0 rgba(51, 51, 51, 0);
              }
            }
            
            @keyframes check {
              50% {
                outline-color: #333;
                box-shadow: 0 0 0 12px #333, 0 0 0 36px rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.2);
              }
              100% {
                outline-color: #333;
                box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 #333, 0 0 0 0 rgba(51, 51, 51, 0);
              }
            }
```

```html
<div class="listing">
    <button onclick="white">White Glass Cooler">
    <button onclick="black">Black Glass Cooler">
    <button onclick="purple">Purple  Glass Cooler">
    <button onclick="blue">Blue Glass Cooler">
</div>
    
<div id="colorPicker">
  <div class="slider">
    <input id="white" style="background:white;" type="radio" name="slider" title="White" checked="checked" class="slider__nav"/>
    <input id="blue" style="background:blue;" type="radio" name="slider" title="Blue" class="slider__nav"/>
    <input id="gold" style="background:gold;" type="radio" name="slider" title="Gold" class="slider__nav"/>
    <input id="green" style="background:green;" type="radio" name="slider" title="Green" class="slider__nav"/>
    <input id="grey" style="background:grey;" type="radio" name="slider" title="Grey" class="slider__nav"/>
    <input id="darkgreen" style="background:darkgreen;" type="radio" name="slider" title="Jade" class="slider__nav"/>
    <input id="darkred" style="background:darkred;" type="radio" name="slider" title="Maroon" class="slider__nav"/>
    <input id="orange" style="background:orange;" type="radio" name="slider" title="Orange" class="slider__nav"/>
    <input id="pink" style="background:pink;" type="radio" name="slider" title="Pink" class="slider__nav"/>
    <input id="red" style="background:red;" type="radio" name="slider" title="Red" class="slider__nav"/>
    <input id="yellow" style="background:yellow;" type="radio" name="slider" title="Yellow" class="slider__nav"/>
  
    <div class="slider__inner">
      <div class="slider__contents"><img src="img/cooler-black.jpg"></div>
      <div class="slider__contents"><img src="img/cooler-blue.jpg"></div>
      <div class="slider__contents"><img src="img/cooler-gold.png"></div>
      <div class="slider__contents"><img src="img/cooler-green.jpg"></div>
      <div class="slider__contents"><img src="img/cooler-grey.png"></div>
      <div class="slider__contents"><img src="img/cooler-jade.png"></div>
      <div class="slider__contents"><img src="img/cooler-maroon.jpg"></div>
      <div class="slider__contents"><img src="img/cooler-orange.jpg"></div>
      <div class="slider__contents"><img src="img/cooler-pink.jpg"></div>
      <div class="slider__contents"><img src="img/cooler-red.jpg"></div>
      <div class="slider__contents"><img src="img/cooler-yellow.jpg"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
<div class="listing">
<button onclick="white">White Glass Cooler">
<button onclick="black">Black Glass Cooler">
<button onclick="purple">Purple  Glass Cooler">
<button onclick="blue">Blue Glass Cooler">
</div>
```

The listing contained the buttons which I am struggling to work out how to make it functional so that when the user click the button both radio and slider_content is selected.

This show one variable product style on selected radio. When you press it the css to move left or right the product image that match the selected radio input.

Can anyone suggest how to remotely select radio when pressed?

Answer (score 0):

on every radio button add an onclick event passing to the same function but with different value (for each radio btn)
what happens in the function you decide..

Answer (score 0):

Please check this example. I have made this for you.

Hope this will helpful for you. Thanks.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("button").removeAttr("checked");
        
     var element = $(this).attr('class');
        $("input").css("border","none");
        $("#" + element).attr('checked', 'checked');
        $("#" + element).css("border","2px solid #000");
        if(element){
         $(".slider__contents").hide();
            $(".slider__contents."+ element).show();
            $(".slider__contents."+ element).css("background",element);
        }
    });
});
```

```css
h1 { display:block; text-align: center;}
        *, *:before, *:after {
          box-sizing: border-box;
        }

       #colorPicker {
         width:400px;
         margin:0 auto;
         height:520px;
         border:1px solid #eaeaea;
       }

        .slider {
          height: 100%;
          width:100%;
          position: relative;
          overflow: hidden;
          display: -webkit-box;
          display: -webkit-flex;
          display: -ms-flexbox;
          display: flex;
          -webkit-flex-flow: row nowrap;
              -ms-flex-flow: row nowrap;
                  flex-flow: row nowrap;
          -webkit-box-align: end;
          -webkit-align-items: flex-end;
              -ms-flex-align: end;
                  align-items: flex-end;
          -webkit-box-pack: center;
          -webkit-justify-content: center;
              -ms-flex-pack: center;
                  justify-content: center;
        }
        .slider__nav {
          width: 30px;
          height: 30px;
          margin: 2rem 5px;
          z-index: 10;
          border:1px solid #BBB;
          cursor: pointer;
          -webkit-appearance: none;
             -moz-appearance: none;
                  appearance: none;
          -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
                  backface-visibility: hidden;
        }
        .slider__nav:checked {
          -webkit-animation: check 0.4s linear forwards;
                  animation: check 0.4s linear forwards;
        }
        .slider__nav:checked:nth-of-type(1) ~ .slider__inner {
          left: 0%;
        }
        .slider__nav:checked:nth-of-type(2) ~ .slider__inner {
          left: -100%;
        }
        .slider__nav:checked:nth-of-type(3) ~ .slider__inner {
          left: -200%;
        }
        .slider__nav:checked:nth-of-type(4) ~ .slider__inner {
          left: -300%;
        }
        .slider__nav:checked:nth-of-type(5) ~ .slider__inner {
          left: -400%;
        }
        .slider__nav:checked:nth-of-type(6) ~ .slider__inner {
          left: -500%;
        }
        .slider__nav:checked:nth-of-type(7) ~ .slider__inner {
          left: -600%;
        }
        .slider__nav:checked:nth-of-type(8) ~ .slider__inner {
          left: -700%;
        }
        .slider__nav:checked:nth-of-type(9) ~ .slider__inner {
          left: -800%;
        }
        .slider__nav:checked:nth-of-type(10) ~ .slider__inner {
          left: -900%;
        }
        .slider__nav:checked:nth-of-type(11) ~ .slider__inner {
          left: -1000%;
        }
        .slider__inner {
          position: absolute;
          top: 0;
          left: 0;
          width: 1100%;
          height: 100%;
          -webkit-transition: left 0.4s;
          transition: left 0.4s;
          display: -webkit-box;
          display: -webkit-flex;
          display: -ms-flexbox;
          display: flex;
          -webkit-flex-flow: row nowrap;
              -ms-flex-flow: row nowrap;
                  flex-flow: row nowrap;
        }
        .slider__contents {
          height: 100%;
          padding: 2rem;
          text-align: center;
          display: -webkit-box;
          display: -webkit-flex;
          display: -ms-flexbox;
          display: flex;

          -webkit-box-flex: 1;
          -webkit-flex: 1;
              -ms-flex: 1;
                  flex: 1;
          -webkit-flex-flow: column nowrap;
              -ms-flex-flow: column nowrap;
                  flex-flow: column nowrap;
          -webkit-box-align: center;
          -webkit-align-items: center;
              -ms-flex-align: center;
                  align-items: center;
          -webkit-box-pack: center;
          -webkit-justify-content: center;
              -ms-flex-pack: center;
                  justify-content: center;
        }


        @-webkit-keyframes check {
          50% {
            outline-color: #333;
            box-shadow: 0 0 0 12px #333, 0 0 0 36px rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.2);
          }
          100% {
            outline-color: #333;
            box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 #333, 0 0 0 0 rgba(51, 51, 51, 0);
          }
        }

        @keyframes check {
          50% {
            outline-color: #333;
            box-shadow: 0 0 0 12px #333, 0 0 0 36px rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.2);
          }
          100% {
            outline-color: #333;
            box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 #333, 0 0 0 0 rgba(51, 51, 51, 0);
          }
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="listing">
<button class="white" onclick="white">White Glass Cooler">
<button class="black" onclick="black">Black Glass Cooler">
<button class="purple" onclick="purple">Purple  Glass Cooler">
<button class="blue" onclick="blue">Blue Glass Cooler">
</div>

<div id="colorPicker">
<div class="slider">
    <input id="white" style="background:white;" type="radio" name="slider" title="White" checked="checked" class="slider__nav"/>
    <input id="blue" style="background:blue;" type="radio" name="slider" title="Blue" class="slider__nav"/>
    <input id="gold" style="background:gold;" type="radio" name="slider" title="Gold" class="slider__nav"/>
    <input id="green" style="background:green;" type="radio" name="slider" title="Green" class="slider__nav"/>
    <input id="grey" style="background:grey;" type="radio" name="slider" title="Grey" class="slider__nav"/>
    <input id="darkgreen" style="background:darkgreen;" type="radio" name="slider" title="Jade" class="slider__nav"/>
    <input id="darkred" style="background:darkred;" type="radio" name="slider" title="Maroon" class="slider__nav"/>
    <input id="orange" style="background:orange;" type="radio" name="slider" title="Orange" class="slider__nav"/>
    <input id="pink" style="background:pink;" type="radio" name="slider" title="Pink" class="slider__nav"/>
    <input id="red" style="background:red;" type="radio" name="slider" title="Red" class="slider__nav"/>
    <input id="yellow" style="background:yellow;" type="radio" name="slider" title="Yellow" class="slider__nav"/>

<div class="slider__inner">
      <div class="slider__contents black"><img src="img/cooler-black.jpg"></div>
      <div class="slider__contents blue"><img src="img/cooler-blue.jpg"></div>
      <div class="slider__contents gold"><img src="img/cooler-gold.png"></div>
      <div class="slider__contents green"><img src="img/cooler-green.jpg"></div>
      <div class="slider__contents grey"><img src="img/cooler-grey.png"></div>
      <div class="slider__contents jade"><img src="img/cooler-jade.png"></div>
      <div class="slider__contents maroon"><img src="img/cooler-maroon.jpg"></div>
      <div class="slider__contents orange"><img src="img/cooler-orange.jpg"></div>
      <div class="slider__contents pink"><img src="img/cooler-pink.jpg"></div>
      <div class="slider__contents red"><img src="img/cooler-red.jpg"></div>
      <div class="slider__contents yellow"><img src="img/cooler-yellow.jpg"></div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The function works but it take away the radio button if the user click on the radio instead of the button under Listing. Also when the button is press I was hoping that make the radio button selected and the image show up controlled by CSS instead of masked with background colour by the script.